# property value cannot be undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, language-lawyer

I am reading a book **JavaScript: The Good Parts** for increasing my JavaScript knowledge. In Chapter 3 Objects the Author says:

> An object is a container of properties, where a property has a name and a value. A property name can be any string, including the empty string. A property value can be any JavaScript value **except for undefined.**

What does the Author mean by that? As far as I know, we can set values to undefined in an object literal or outside of an object literal using with prototype word.  For example `Object.prototype.customName = undefined;` works well. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing nothing. Unless there's some context there you're not including (I haven't read it myself), that particular point on its own is incorrect.

Comment: I just downloaded the book and read the part you mentioned, considering the book was released in 2008 it could very well be that at that time (ECMAScript 3) you couldn't set `undefined` for an Object key's value.

Comment: @prsvr Not sure if you saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105908/property-value-cannot-be-undefined-in-javascript#comment85217812_49106055), but I don't believe the semantics of setting a property to `undefined` have changed since ECMAScript 3, so I'm pretty sure we can't dismiss the author's claim as "outdated"; it's just incorrect.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Maybe he fixes it in 2nd version if it ever comes to life, which it should considering it's been 10 years and 2 new releases of ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you can assign the value `undefined` to a property, and even define a literal with the `undefined` property; however, the resulting object is *very easily confused* with the similar object written without that property.

For example, in Node:

```
> x = {a: 1, b: undefined}
{ a: 1, b: undefined }
> y = {a: 1}
{ a: 1 }
> x.a
1
> y.a
1
> x.b
undefined
> y.b
undefined
> Object.keys(x)
[ 'a', 'b' ]
> Object.keys(y)
[ 'a' ]
> JSON.stringify(x)
'{"a":1}'
> JSON.stringify(y)
'{"a":1}'
```

It appears the author is saying that if you want to write good, responsible code, you should not use `undefined` as a property value, because you could asking for confusion.

But semantically, that `undefined` is really there, so if you interpret what the author is saying literally, it's technically incorrect. But if you follow best practices, I can see what he's trying to get across. It's very Crockford-esque.

By the way, the right way to remove properties is with `delete` but that's perhaps for a different question.

**ADDENDUM**

In response to a question in the comments from @prsvr, I looked up the old ECMAScript 3 Specification and found the following:

> ECMAScript is object-based: basic language and host facilities are provided by objects, and an ECMAScript program is a cluster of communicating objects. An ECMAScript object is an unordered collection of properties each with zero or more attributes that determine how each property can be used—for example, when the ReadOnly attribute for a property is set to true, any attempt by executed ECMAScript code to change the value of the property has no effect. Properties are containers that hold other objects, primitive values, or methods. A  ECMAScript Language primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String; an object is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String; an object is a member of the remaining built-in type Object; and a method is a function associated with an object via a property.

There is no mention of `undefined` being disallowed as property values in the spec. (https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf).

There were changes to undefined during the evolution of JavaScript; for example you used to be able to reassign the value of the *identifier* `undefined` to some value other than undefined, hence the idiom `typeof(x) === "undefined"` (among others).

Comment: Could it be that `undefined` was allowed as a value in later releases of JS ?

Comment: To expand on your point about "very easily confused", a common case is the erroneous check for a property's existence by doing `x.b === undefined` or `typeof x.b === 'undefined'` or similar. The correct way for checking a property _if it is enumerable_ is `'b' in x`, or if it is an own, non-enumerable property, `x.hasOwnProperty('b')`. If is not an own, or enumerable property, checking for its existence when it is `undefined` is a bit more involved, and perhaps out of scope for this question.

Comment: Hmm, good point @prsvr, that may have been true in ES3 (pre-2009) and ES5 (2009-2015) days.

Comment: @RayToal It was still at version 3 at the time that book was released.

Comment: Quite right, December 2008 is the publication date on that.

Comment: Looking at the [ECMAScript 3 specification](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf) and comparing it to the [ECMAScript 5.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), 3 didn't have definitions for §4.3.24-31 which included "property", "own property" and "inherited property". However, they did both contain the `in` operator in §11.8.7, and both specifications reference the internal [[HasProperty]] method and define `in` semantically the same, which leads me to believe that the author's claim in the book is simply erroneous and not due to being outdated.

Comment: I think you're right. I suppose, too, we could always ask him what he meant by that statement. :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts So you imply a developer should read the newer books include modern ES6 or ES.Next explanations. There might be so popular or accepted in their era but now they are outdated. Is that true?

Comment: @oyilmaztekin I'm not implying anything about what a developer should do, other than follow up their reading with critical research to confirm that everything they learned is indeed correct. So kudos to you for listening to your gut instead of taking the author's word without question.

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable information you gave. @PatrickRoberts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author is trying to say that a key of an object cannot be defined without defining its value. That is, a key should always have a value.

For example if the key `test` is defined without defining its value, it will throw an error.

```js
var abc = {
  test:
}
```

Comment: If that was what the author meant then why would they explicitly say "except for undefined"? Why does "can be any JavaScript value" not suffice for this case?

Answer (score 0):

i think because js object consider `undefined` is default value for both `inactive key` and `unknown key`

```js
var person = {
   name: 'name',
   '': 'this is empty key',
   null: 'this is null key',
   another_null: null,
   undefined: 'this is undefined key',
   inactive_key: undefined  
}
console.log(person['key_from_nowhere']) // unknown key => undefined
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('key_from_nowhere')) // false
console.log(person['inactive_key']) // undefined
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('inactive_key')) // true
```

so that if you assign value of a object's key to `undefined` then this key fall into the `inactive key` case (JSON.stringify will ignore)

```
person.name = undefined;
console.log(JSON.stringify(person)); // name will disappear
```

BTW, i see that assign `undefined` maybe cause confuse and error prone since logic code must use `hasOwnProperty` to check the key exist or not, so do you think that the best practice here is `do not assign undefined` ?